# MongoDB check if list item exists for an item in collection before inserting to DB

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

Im developing a django application uisng python and mongoDB. Im developing  a form and take user inputs and save to DB.
 Before inserting i want to check if data is already present DB.

I have a mongo collection which looks something like below :

coll_1 :

```
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d5"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-11-18T10:23:29.620Z"), "City_list" : "[PN-City1, PN-City2,PN-City3, PN-City4]", "LDE" :  "LDE-1234, LDE-345, LDE-456" , "Name": "ABC"}
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fba49d6"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-18T10:23:29.620Z"), "City_list" : "[PN-City4, PN-City5,PN-City6,PN- City7]", "LDE" : "LDE-444, LDE-3445, LDE-456", "Name": "BCD"}
  { "_id" : ObjectId("56e0a3a2d59feaa43fd67873"), "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-12-18T10:23:29.620Z"), "City_list" : "[PN-City1, PN-City6,PN-City9,PN- City10]", "LDE" : "LDE-444, LDE-3445, LDE-456", "Name": "XYZ"}
```

I have a form from where i take user inputs : Name, Cities (one or more comma separated), LDE (comma separated)

In my script i want to check before inserting into mongodb 
If the user is new user insert directly db.
If old user, check if cities inputed by user is present in db already if not update db else throw a messagee to html with message saying city already present in DB.

Say my input is something like this :

```
 Name: PQR
 City_list : PN-City4, PN-City12
 LDE: LDE-6767
```

My code is as below :

```
if 'Name' in pdata and ('city_list' in pdata and re.match("(PN-\w*-\d)(PN-\w*-\d)*",  pdata['city_list'])):
user_input = pdata['city_list'].split(",")
pname = pdata['Name']
for data in user_input:
    if db.coll_1.find({"Name": pname , 'City_list': { "$in": data}})
```

This is giving me error.

How do i achieve this

I tried something like this :

```
for data in user_input:
    data = str(data) # it was taking as unicode
    if (db.coll_1.find({"Name": pname , 'City_list': { "$in": data}}).count() > 0):


Gives error : OperationFailure: $in needs an array
```

CIty_list  is a string

Can some one please help me with this

Comment: what's the error exactly? Where is 'UserIDS' in yout coll1_1 schema? City_list is really as string in mongo? (you can use a mongo list)

Comment: @Nadav sorry i by mistake added another test query. I have edited it .
Thing is now its if condition works for any input

Comment: The problem is with `str(data)` and you need a list to use "$in". To avoid the error,try: `data = [str(data)]`
But I keep my comment above: "Citi_list is really as string"? Why you do not keep it as an array?

Comment: Yeah i tried that as well.. No error. But if condition fails  even if newly added city is already in City_list.
Regarding City_list being entered as string. It was initially entered thatw ay changing now might impact other aggregate queries

Comment: so if you need to put City_list as string your query can't use "$in". You'll need to use a regex query to find data in City_list

Comment: how do i modify the above find query ? use s match ? any example ?

Comment: i'm not sure, but try something like:

db.coll_1.find({"username" : {$regex : ".*{0}.*".format(data)}});

Comment: How do i find if the field is actually string or array?